# Switching from one solution to another in visual sudio

Tags: visual-studio

I have been able to bring a number of projects together like this:

[image: Solutions]

But now, whenever I try to switch from "Bitmap Loading and Drawing" sln(do realize bold letters) to another sln, I am unable to do so.

I even tried to click on another sln's file. It does come out but if I try to build the latter sln file... the former sln gets built.

what is the correct way to switch from one solution to another?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "switch" between projects in vs right click the project you want to switch to and choose the "Set as start up project" option

The project you are currently in or the one which will be built if you  "start" is the one that is highlighted bold in the project explorer.